# SharePoint Lists - edit columns not hiding/showing

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, list-form, formula

I have a choice column named "Catalogue". one of the choices is Digital. I have another choice column named Digital Strategy Areas that I only want to show when Digital is selected from Catalogue.

My conditional formula for the Digital Strategy Areas is:

```
=if([$Catalogue] == 'Digital', 'true', 'false')
```

[image]

[image]

the column goes grey when I hit save, however it does not show up when i select Digital in Catalogue as you can see above, and I don't know why?

Comment: Catalogue is single selection choice column or multiple selection choice column?

Comment: its a choice column but it does not allow multiple sections

Comment: ok, please check my answer given below and verify all points. Let me know if it works for you or if you still facing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SharePoint conditional formula and syntax looks good to me.

I will suggest you to verify below things:

1. Make sure you are using correct **internal name** of "Catalogue" in the SharePoint conditional formula. You can get the exact internal name of your SharePoint columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)
2. Make sure you are using the formula with exact case as shown in your question - `if`, `true` and `false`, etc. should be in small letters as it might not work with capital or mixed letters.
3. Make sure `Catalogue` column is a choice column with single selection allowed as choice columns with multiple selections are not supported in SharePoint conditional formulas.

Check this Microsoft official documentation for more information and steps to apply conditional formulas in SharePoint list forms: [Show or hide columns in a SharePoint list or library form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-conditional-show-hide)

Comment: thank you Ganesh, once i checked the internal name of the Catalogue column in the url link, it was set to an old column name "Catalogueofservices". once i changed the conditional formula to that column name, it now works! thanks again

Comment: You're welcome, I am glad it worked for you!